# Integrating tldraw with existing nextjs app

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have an existing next.js application, and I am trying to add tldraw to it. I have enabled typescript, and I have tried to run an example found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/n539u?file=/src/App.tsx, but I continue to get the following error:

```
Server Error
ReferenceError: window is not defined

ReferenceError: window is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/@tldraw/tldraw/dist/index.js:76:31285)
```

Here are the relevant dependencies used for this project:

```
"dependencies": {
"@tldraw/tldraw": "^1.28.0",
"next": "13.0.5",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
}
```

Has anyone had the same issue?

TLDraw can be found here: https://github.com/tldraw/tldraw

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure loading tldraw on client and not on server rendering.

you can either use useEffect to load tldraw on client specifically or use suspense to load it asyncronously.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).